# Auto-updating images folder in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there some a better way to import images to Xcode than dragging them into project/group/subgroup etc... Not mentioning the creating of retina & non-retina version - I know there are scripts for that, but if there was a way to faster this routine it would be great!

The best way that comes to my mind is that I just copy the into proper folder and it appears in the project in associated group in both retina & non-retina versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder Actions is another option? i.e. right click on a folder i.e. the folder you save the images to from whichever is your favourite editor, click on "Services" then on "Folder Action Setup" and set up an automator workflow to do this.

Set up a simple "move file from..to" workflow i.e. from the folder you save images to, to the folder you have set up as a group in Xcode.

Comment: This can solve the issue with retina & non-retina but still you have to put them into correct folder and then drag them into correct group.

Comment: so use a naming convention when you save them i.e.
a_c_imageName.png -> XcodeProjectRoot->AssetsGroup->CustomGroup
a_m_imageName.png -> XcodeProjectRoot->AssetsGroup->MyOtherGroup

Ideally images should really be imported into Images.xcassets rather than anywhere else. Which too would make things a little more complicated as theres json files in there.

Comment: did this help? It'd be interesting to know :)